# VBA coding on access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to see where my issue lies with the following code.

```
'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO IB Students(Student Name, Gender, IB) " & _
"VALUES (" & Me.Text6 & ",'" & Me.Combo13 & "','" & Me.Text9 & "')"

'refresh data in list on form
stdfrm.Form.Requery
```

Whenever I try to use the add command I get `Runtime Error -3134` and it says there is a syntax error with `INSERT INTO` statement.

Comment: Please add more verbiage to your question. The code should work in theory.

Comment: Whenever i try to use the add command i get "Runtime Error- 3134"

Comment: It says there is a syntax error in the 'INSERT INTO' statement

Comment: This has SQL injection vulnerabilities and should be parameterized, see what happens if you put a ' in Me.Text6

Answer (score 3):

May be the name of table needs to be enclosed by brackets, and text values must be quoted:

```
'add data to table
sSQL = "INSERT INTO [IB Students] ([Student Name], Gender, IB) " & _
"VALUES ('" & Me.Text6 & "','" & Me.Combo13 & "','" & Me.Text9 & "')"

'print SQL for debug
Debug.print sSQL  

'Run query
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL

'refresh data in list on form
stdfrm.Form.Requery
```

Note: if `Me.Text6` (and others) is not bind to data source then you must use it as `Me.Text6.Value`

Edit: Maybe is a good idea check the length before run the query

Comment: Ditto for `[Student Name]`

Comment: Yes you right @AlexK.  I just modified my answer... Thank you

Comment: I am still getting the same 3134 runtime error but this time the debugger is pointed at "CurrentDb.Execute sSQL"

Comment: What is the printed SQL? (Press Alt+F11, then go to immediate window)

Comment: **Alt+F11** to go to the **VBA window**, **CTRL+G** to go for the **Immediate window**.

Comment: @AhsenRauf assuming this solution still doesn't work, there's probably an issue with one of the values in the textboxes or combobox. Follow the suggestions of others to find out what the `sSQL` string has in it and post that back into your question.

Answer (score 0):

When i open the immediate window it shows

```
    INSERT INTO [IB Students] (Student Name, Gender, IB) VALUES (Micheal,'Male','2')
INSERT INTO [IB Students] (Student Name, Gender, IB) VALUES (John,'Male','1')
INSERT INTO [IB Students] ([Student Name], Gender, IB) VALUES (,'','')
INSERT INTO [IB Students] ([Student Name], Gender, IB) VALUES (,'','')
```